# Show that if a function $f : R \to R$ is continuous and $<x_n>$ is Cauchy, then $(f(x_n))_n$ is also Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if a function $f : R \to R$ is continuous and $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy, then $(f(x_n))_n$ is also Cauchy sequence. Here, the problem is that it is not specified that $f$ is uniformly continuous. And I didn't learn about uniformly continuous function yet, how would I prove it? Where should I start?

Comment: False for the rationals in place of the reals.  So any proof of this would require use of completeness.

Comment: Ok, I get what you all say, but the problem is I do not know what exactly my professor wants....Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't  this trivial? Since $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy sequence, it converges, say $x:= \lim_n x_n$. But $f$ is continuous, so $f(x) = \lim_n f(x_n)$ and thus $(f(x_n))_n$ is Cauchy as well.

Basically this is just a restatement of saying that a continuous functions maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences.

Comment: So I can just say that since $x_n$ converges to $x$ and $f(x)=limf(x_n)$, $(f(x_n))_n$ is convergent therefore Cauchy?

Comment: Yes, in complete metric spaces: a sequence is a Cauchy sequence if and only if it is convergent.

Comment: What I am worried about is that my professor seems to want to see some complicated proof ...Thank you very much for helping me out!

Comment: You are welcome!